# FlexLayoutModule not working with Angular 11

Tags: angular, flexbox

I updated to version 11 today. My package json is below. The FlexLayoutModule no longer engages and formats the divs with the directives. It doesn't appear that anything happens at all, but I don't get any error messages. Here is my package.json and the app module.

I did find some chatter on github showing that version 10 of Flex did not work when Angular 11 came out. The discussion seemed to just end without any conclusion. Any help is great.

```
{
  "name": "mak-clean",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@ngrx/data": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^8.1.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I tried injecting the Flex Module into my feature module, but that didn't help. Here is my app module showing it injected.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


// Mak Studio Modules
import { LoginModule } from './main/Common/login/login.module';
import { ProfileModule } from './main/profile/profile.module';
import { NavbarModule } from './main/Shared/navbar/navbar.module';


// Google Firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


// NGRX Items
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { metaReducers, reducers } from '../app/main/store/reducers';
import { EntityDataModule } from '@ngrx/data';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { RouterState, StoreRouterConnectingModule } from '@ngrx/router-store';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // Standard modules
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    // Mak modules
    LoginModule,
    NavbarModule,
    ProfileModule,


    // Firestore Auth Modules
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,


    // NGRX items
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks : {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true,
        strictStateSerializability:true
      }
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    EntityDataModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      stateKey: 'router',
      routerState: RouterState.Minimal
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you get any warnings in your terminal after executing a `npm i`?

Comment: I did, but I rolled back to version 10 and resolved those. The flex is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update all dependencies at once. Please try,`npm update @angular/material @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating @angular/cdk as per angular 11. As https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1100-beta33-2020-11-12 says to use @angular/cdk v11.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on angular 11, and installed angular flex-layout module, by default. Your package manager will install the latest version, which is not compatible with your angular version.

You can find all installed packages in your package.json in the ROOT directory of your application. For example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34"
}
```

To install the correct version, simply add the version at the end of your npm command:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33
```

If you want to uninstall your angular flex-layout package, you can do it with:

npm uninstall @angular/flex-layout